# Guest User can perform update under future method

Tags: future, guest-user

I have a site page with a form that can be accessed by guest users. I have an upload button that when it's clicked a tracking record is created (it's ok for guest user as the profile has read/create) but when submitting the form I run an upsert over the tracking record, that was causing an exception for the guest user. I tried doing the update on a future method if the user was a guest and it worked. My question is, why if the running context of a future method is the same (guest user) update runs successfully? Is this an expected behavior? Thanks!

Comment: Does your class has with sharing?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava no, it does not have sharing declaration. But without the future method I receive the error anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but...
Any errors occurring in a @future method will not show up in the debug log for this call, as it will run in a new context, generating a new, separate debug log for the same user.

Any errors will show up there.

Bonus: The result of the @future call, plus error status, will be visible in setup, under "Apex Jobs".